# delete posts on rails server from heroku console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, afnetworking

I am developing a rails-backed iOS app that is running on Heroku. The app uses afnetworking to GET and POST to the server. As I am developing it, I make posts to test and see if http requests are working- and they do, but I have all of these test posts that I would like to get rid of.
Is there a way to clean off the production server? Can I delete posts from the console?
I am new to this so any advice about monitoring the server would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the below command to clear your DB.

```
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE_URL
```